# How can I find memory leaks without external packages?

Tags: python, mysql-connector-python

I am writing a data mining script to pull information off of a program called Agisoft PhotoScan for my lab. PhotoScan uses its own Python library (and I'm not sure how to access pip for this particular build), which has caused me a few problems installing other packages. After dragging, dropping, and praying, I've gotten a few packages to work, but I'm still facing a memory leak. If there is no way around it, I can try to install some more packages to weed out the leak, but I'd like to avoid this if possible.

My understanding of Python garbage collection so far is, when an object loses its reference, it should be deleted. I used sys.getrefcount() to check all my variables, but they all stay constant. I have a hunch that the issue could be in the mysql-connector package I installed, or in PhotoScan itself, but I am not sure how to go about testing. I will be more than happy to provide code if that will help!

Comment: Garbage collection also runs at increments based on what the deleted data was. https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/

Comment: Hmm, is there a way I can manually delete data then?

Comment: It seems mysql-connector has a reputation for not performing well. I will try to rewrite the program to use mysqlclient and see how it works.

Comment: You can control garbage collection with python's `gc` module: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/gc.html

Comment: Got it, I'll take a look around. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the memory leak was indeed with the PhotoScan program. I've worked around it by having a separate script open and close it, running my original script once each time. Thank you all for the help!